# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I was going through the flashloan course and I was having trouble with section 13 Pull Kyber Prices.

I am getting this error

> (node:43614) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first

Here is my full code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Web3 = require('web3');
const abis = require('./abis');
const { mainnet: addresses } = require('./addresses');

const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(process.env.INFURA_URL)
);

const kyber = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abis.kyber.kyberNetworkProxy,
  addresses.kyber.kyberNetworProxy  
);

const AMOUNT_ETH = 100;
const RECENT_ETH_PRICE = 2400;
const AMOUNT_ETH_WEI = web3.utils.toWei(AMOUNT_ETH.toString());
const AMOUNT_DAI_WEI = web3.utils.toWei((AMOUNT_ETH * RECENT_ETH_PRICE).toString());

web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders')
    .on('data', async block => {
        console.log('New Block Recieved # ' + block.number);

        const kyberResult = await Promise.all([
            kyber
                .methods
                .getExpectedRate(
                    addresses.tokens.dai,
                    '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
                    AMOUNT_DAI_WEI
                )
                .call(),
            kyber
                .methods
                .getExpectedRate(
                    '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
                    addresses.tokens.dai,
                    AMOUNT_ETH_WEI
                )
                .call()
        ]);
        console.log(kyberResults);

    })
    .on('error', error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
```

The error that I am getting is this:

```
    (node:43614) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.
    at Object.ContractNoAddressDefinedError (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:122:16)
    at Object._processExecuteArguments (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:728:22)
    at Object._executeMethod (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:744:68)
    at Subscription.<anonymous> (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/run-arbitrage.js:34:18)
    at Subscription.emit (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/eventemitter3/index.js:181:35)
    at /Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/lib/subscription.js:242:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.callback (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions/lib/subscription.js:234:28)
    at WebsocketProvider.data (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:99:73)
    at WebsocketProvider.emit (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/eventemitter3/index.js:181:35)
    at /Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:104:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/wealthywhyte/Desktop/Solidity/profitable-flashloanz/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:43614) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:43614) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I believe that the problem is lines 31 and 38 after the method ".getExpectedRate" I am just not sure what to switch those addresses that he provided out with.